# How to display multiple image in thumbnail and Not able to play audio in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS programming. I'm fetching images and audios file from server. After that, using below code, I am trying to display all images as a thumbnail. Can any one tell me how can I display all images as a thumbnail. Also audio is not playing.

```
-(IBAction)fullsizeimage:(id)sender
{
 ////////////// Image ////////////////////////////  

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/uploads/45/thumbnail_small/326.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    imagee = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    [self.view addSubview:imagee];
 NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/uploads/45/thumbnail_small/327.png"];
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url1];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:data1];
    imagee1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image1];
    [self.view addSubview:imagee1];
NSURL *urll = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/uploads/45/thumbnail_small/325.png"];
    NSData *dataa = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: urll];
    UIImage *imageee = [UIImage imageWithData:dataa];
    imagee2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imageee];
    [self.view addSubview:imagee2];

///////////////  Audio ///////////////////////

   NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://182.73.152.59:82/php/tauky_services/codeigniter-restserver-master/uploads/45/Audio/312.mp3"];
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audiourl];

    NSError *error;
    //AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioData error:&error];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog([error description]);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];

}
```

Thanks
Aslam

Answer (score 0):

Consider assigning a different frame to each image before you add them to the `superview`. It's possible that your code assigns the same frame for each image.

Use `NSLog(@"%@", [self.view subviews]);` to know if the image views are present and loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Set different UIImageView (with your required thumbnail frame) on your main view and then add these image's on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cosider using a GridView from the  [moriarty library](http://bynomial.com/moriarty/), either as a large grid in a UIScrollView, or on a more efficient row-by-row basis in a UITableView.

You could use TTPhotoViewController from the 
[Three20 project](http://foo.com), which works as iOS built in camera roll to view images.